# Adding values to array hash ruby at a specific position

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a hash response object which looks like this :

```
jsonResponse = {:json=>{"reply"=>[{"person"=>"abc", "roll_no"=>"1234", "location"=>"loc1", "score"=>"1"}, {"person"=>"def", "roll_no"=>"1235", "location"=>"loc2", "score"=>"2"},{"person"=>"fgh", "roll_no"=>"1236", "location"=>"loc3", "score"=>"3"}]}, :status=>200}
```

I have to add one key value pair **at a specific position** to each of these reply array objects, so that the response transforms to something like this , to make it simpler for now, lets try adding a samke key value pair at a particular position:

```
jsonResponse = {:json=>{"reply"=>[{"person"=>"abc", "roll_no"=>"1234","location"=>"loc1", "new_value => "new_result", "score"=>"1"}, {"person"=>"def", "roll_no"=>"1235", "location"=>"loc2","new_value => "new_result", "score"=>"2"},{"person"=>"fgh", "roll_no"=>"1236", "location"=>"loc3", "new_value => "new_result", "score"=>"3"}]}, :status=>200}
```

This is what I have tried ,I run .each through jsonResponse :

```
jsonResponse[:json]['reply'].each do |object|
               objectArray = object.to_a
               insert_at = objectArray.index(objectArray.assoc('score'))
               object = Hash[objectArray.insert(insert_at, ['new_value','new_result'])]
               print("\n\nTest\n\n")
               print object
      end
    print("\n\nFinal Response\n\n")
    print jsonResponse
```

The ***object*** which i am printing has the desired response but it does not get updated in the ***jsonResponse***

This is the output of the above code snippet:

```
Test

{"person"=>"abc", "roll_no"=>"1234", "location"=>"loc1", "new_value"=>"new_result", "score"=>"1"}

Test

{"person"=>"def", "roll_no"=>"1235", "location"=>"loc2", "new_value"=>"new_result", "score"=>"2"}

Test

{"person"=>"fgh", "roll_no"=>"1236", "location"=>"loc3", "new_value"=>"new_result", "score"=>"3"}

Final Response

{:json=>{"reply"=>[{"person"=>"abc", "roll_no"=>"1234", "location"=>"loc1", "score"=>"1"}, {"person"=>"def", "roll_no"=>"1235", "location"=>"loc2", "score"=>"2"}, {"person"=>"fgh", "roll_no"=>"1236", "location"=>"loc3", "score"=>"3"}]}, :status=>200}
```

**Q2.** Also as you can see from the code snippet the ***insert_at*** logic works in a way that it adds before the position we specify , for eg it adds before **score key**, is there a logic which i can write which adds to the **position after the specified key** and not before?

Appreciate the efforts by everyone

Comment: Hashes only order by insertion... order which should only effect iteration. So you're going to have to remove everything and re-insert, or read and create a new hash. I would ask what the purpose of this exercise is? If you're accessing the hash/json by index position later on in the data transfer you should look at new ways of access.

Comment: @benjessop , I am receiving the jsonResponse from a service reply in my api , i have posted the snippet according to particular use case, i am open to different ways of reading jsonResponse, but i have to insert the key value pair based on a particularly existing key

Comment: You should note that although since Ruby 1.9 the insertion order of hash items is preserved, there is no such restriction in the JSON standard and in many other languages that support the hash pattern. In JSON, the ordering of attributes in an object is not specified and should not be relied on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given three objects.

```
jsonResponse = {
  :json=>{
    "reply"=>[
      {"person"=>"abc", "roll_no"=>"1234", "location"=>"loc1", "score"=>"1"},
      {"person"=>"def", "roll_no"=>"1235", "location"=>"loc2", "score"=>"2"}, 
      {"person"=>"fgh", "roll_no"=>"1236", "location"=>"loc3", "score"=>"3"}
    ]
  },
  :status=>200
}

key_value_pair_to_add = { 'new_value'=>'new_result' }
key_to_precede = 'location'
```

We then modify `jsonResponse` as follows.

```
keys_to_shift = jsonResponse[:json]['reply'][0].keys.
  drop_while { |k| k != key_to_precede }        
  #=> ["location", "score"]
jsonResponse[:json]['reply'].each do |h| 
  h.update('new_value'=>'new_result')
  keys_to_shift.each { |k| h.update(k=>h.delete(k)) }
end
```

```
jsonResponse
  #=> {
  #     :json=>{
  #       "reply"=>[
  #         {"person"=>"abc", "roll_no"=>"1234", "new_value"=>"new_result",
  #          "location"=>"loc1", "score"=>"1"},
  #         {"person"=>"def", "roll_no"=>"1235", "new_value"=>"new_result",
  #          "location"=>"loc2", "score"=>"2"},
  #         {"person"=>"fgh", "roll_no"=>"1236", "new_value"=>"new_result",
  #          "location"=>"loc3", "score"=>"3"}
  #       ]
  #     },
  #     :status=>200
  #   }
```

See [Hash#update](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) and [Hash#delete](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-delete).

```
h.delete('location')
```

removes the key-value pair `'location'=>'locX'` from `h` and returns `locX`, after which

```
h.update('location'=>'locX')
```

returns that key-value pair to the end of the hash. This is repeated for each key in `keys_to_shift`.

Answer (score 0):

Give a simple example:

```rb
# define order 
order = [:first, :second, :third]
# the hash you want to order by
json = { :third=>"3", :second=>2, :first=>1 }

result = json.sort_by { |k, _| order.index(k) }.to_h
```

then result will be `{:first=>1, :second=>2, :third=>"3"}`

Comment: This is far too static to use for any realtime application.